# Assigning window.location.href value to const variable throwing security exception in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, window.location

I'm trying to assign window.location.href value to const variable as below in my application,

```
const currentWindowPath = existingWindowItem.window.location.href;
```

this getting failed with security exception of "Blocked a frame with origin http://localhost:4200 from accessing a cross origin frame.

need assistance to hold currentWindowPath to hold the href value, to further compare variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. You cannot access properties of a frame from a different domain, in general.

Comment: Thanks Pointy for the response. So, is there any way to read the value of existingWindowItem.window.location.href and hold it in some variable.

Comment: Well from what you posted it's really hard to say; what are those variables? Where do they get their values? What are the elements involved in your page? People cannot read your mind.

Comment: As Pointy pointed out (:-)) - there is not enough info here. What is existingWindowItem?

Comment: consider a following case...as below, to put my thoughts here...hope it bit clear..
 'const path = "having url"
 existingWindowItem.window.location.href = path;
    const currentWindowPath = existingWindowItem.window.location.href;'
 if currentWindowPath is not equla to variable path , then log message in console as incorrect url.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn’t help. Your problem is not how to compare, but what exactly you want to compare. If one of the things your trying to compare is from an external iframe, it won’t work, at least not buy reading location.href (you can read the original  iframe URL  though). Do you have control over the contents of the iFrame? If so, there is a solution. If not, you’re out of luck.